# Flatten Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: This is my dataframe]

I have a dataframe which has two column 'Year' and 'Month' and date of month 1 to 31. Now, i need a dataframe which has four columns 'Year', 'Month', 'Day' and 'Value'. Just like below:

```
Year  Month  Day Value
1989  1      1   0
1989  1      2   0
..................
..................
2018  12     1   5
2018  12     2   7
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) would solve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), setting `Year` and `Month` as `id_vars`:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Year', 'Month'], var_name='Day')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot yatu for your answer